# Unable to find the line for exc_bad_access with exception break point and and setting a NSZombies class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

The code is supposed to make chunks of data of an image selected from a picker view and upload it to a website , but every time i try to upload a particular chunk it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.The following is the code for splitting the image data in chunks

```
PrimaryImageController.h

@interface PrimaryImageViewController
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong)    NSMutableArray *chunkArray;


PrimaryImageController.m
@synthesize imgView,chunkArray;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
chunkArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void)updateImage
{
UIImage *img = imgView.image;    
NSData *dataObj=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
NSUInteger length = [dataObj length];    
NSUInteger chunkSize = 3072*10;
NSUInteger offset = 0;
int numberOfChunks=0;
do
{
    NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
    NSData* chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[dataObj bytes] + offset
                                         length:thisChunkSize
                                   freeWhenDone:NO];
    offset += thisChunkSize;        
    [chunkArray insertObject:chunk atIndex:numberOfChunks];        
    numberOfChunks++;        
}    
while (offset < length);
for (int i=0; i<[chunkArray count]; i++)
{
    [uploadPrimary uploadImage:[chunkArray objectAtIndex:i] uuid:uniqueIdString numberOfChunks:[chunkArray count] currentChunk:i];
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `chunkArray` defined?

Comment: @RichardBrown Its defined in the viewDidLoad of the controller.

Comment: Can you add the definition and allocation?

Comment: @RichardBrown added the definition & allocation of imgView and the chunkArray

Comment: Did you get any messages in the console window when you crashed?

Comment: @OwenHartnett No i did not get any message on the console ....The only  error i got is _CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2):

`exc_bad_access` indicates a hard crash, no more, no less.   While over-releasing objects often leads to such, there are many other reasons why such a crash might happen.   As well, a hard crash is not an exception in the `NSException` sense;  setting an exception breakpoint won't help.

If you have a crash, you should have a backtrace.  Post the backtrace of the crash.

If you have ARC enabled, this looks like an interior pointer problem.   You are creating a bunch of references to data contained in `dataObj`, but never referring to `dataObj` again.

Try adding `[dataObj self];` after that `for()` loop.

However, since you are storing the chunks in an array that is an instance variable, the lifespan of `dataObj` should be coupled to the lifespan of that array.   I.e. either move the array into the `updateImage` method or declare an iVar to strong reference `dataObj`.